# How to rbind multiple data.frames with same column names but in a different order

Tags: r, rbind

as above, I want to rbind multiple data frames from multiple participants. They all have the same names but in different orders, so for example dat1 has
`participant  rating1  rating2  rating3` 
and dat2 has `participant rating1  rating3  rating2` when I try to use rbind(dat1, dat2) I get the error that the names does not match.

Is there a possibility to sort/order them (and of course keeping the data in the right columns)?

Comment: You could try `dplyr::bind_rows` or you could order the columns so that the order in each df is the same.

Comment: Try `dat2 <- dat2[, c("participant", "rating1",  "rating2",  "rating3")]` or `dat2 <- dat2[, names(dat1)]`

Comment: Thank you :) I think it already worked with the bind_rows()

Comment: Yep. With `bind_rows` the order does not matter.